# interaction between Javascript and haskell (stdin/stdout)

Tags: javascript, haskell, io

I have an exercise to do where:

- we need to write a program in whatever language we want (I picked haskell),
  that program take stdin and return stdout (in an endless while loop fashion).
  *this part works fine when I try it from terminal*
- then a provided JS server must call the program we wrote give inputs and do something with its output. (actually the JS server is supposed to call a bash script that call the program but that, I can hack around)
  *this part does not work (the server works fine when interacting with golang version but its sounds unresponsive with my haskell version)*

here is a simplified snippet of the haskell IO loop:

```
main = do
  guess_loop []

guess_loop xs = do
  x <- readLn
  let new_list = x:xs
  putStr $ show $ doSmothing new_list
  putStr "\n"
  guess_loop new_list
```

this is the snippet JS that communicate with my program (I think):

```
  //executes the program with the numbers as stdin entries and saves its ouput in `output`
  let output
  try {
    output = execSync(test_file, {
      input: values_to_test,
    })
  } catch (err) {
    res.send({ status: 500, msg: 'No file found: ' + guesser })
    throw Error('No file found\n' + err)
  }

  let value = output.toString().split('\n')
  value.pop()

  let result = 0
  let returning = []
  let correct = 0
```

and here is the simplified working golang version snippet

```
func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    var k []float64
    for reader.Scan() {
        t := reader.Text()
        n, err := strconv.Atoi(t)
        k = append(k, float64(n))
        fmt.PrintLn(do_something(k)) // return []float64
    }
}
```

**I have no clue of JS (and do not need any), I know some golang , I am learning haskell**

nothing actually happen so no error to share.

I understood that the lazy aspect of haskell regarding IO could be at play, so I added
`hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering hSetBuffering stdout LineBuffering`
before the IO loop (below `main = do`) in vain.

I tried to put console.log('hint') everywhere is JS code to figure out what is happening with no luck. I also made haskell IO loop to write output in a file to check if it was actually active when called by JS and it did.

My guts tells me there is something off between
`try { output = execSync(test_file,inputs}`
and
`PutStr result`

If you can help me in any way: spot an obvious error or put me on the right track; that would be great. Ideally I would rather do something about the haskell and leave untouched the JS one.
If you have any clue please share.
Thanks

Comment: To see if that's a buffering problem, you can try running `hFlush stdout` just before each `readLn` or similar actions that wait for input.

Comment: Are you sure the problem exists in your simplified version? It does look like this should behave exactly the same as the Go version. (And I don't hink buffering has anything to do with the problem, since you're giving the entire input and read the entire output.)

Comment: thanks @chi, I actually tried that one, I did not mentioned it because I thought that 
`hSetBuffering stdout LineBuffering` 
before the loop was more or less the same thing as `hFlush stdout` into the loop

Comment: @leftaroundabout well I tried many things and added buffering things at the very last.
both go and hs version always behaved the same when started manually from terminal.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code, but just to be sure, I'd write `let new_list :: [Int] ; new_list = x:xs` so to provide an explicit type for that. (Replace `Int` with the intended type.) I'm wondering if some unintended type is being inferred instead. Also, `readLn` can crash when the input is ill-formed, but I guess you are not seeing that crash (?).

Comment: This could use a minimal reproducible example (and instructions for people like me that may know Haskell well but Javascript not at all on how to run it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem may be that your example program reads input forever, and when it encounters an end of file, **it terminates with an error**.  The Golang version reads input until it encounters an end of file and then gracefully exits.

The Javascript driver appears to provide a finite amount of input from `values_to_test`, and it responds to any failure of the program to run successfully with a `500 No File Found` error, ignoring any output that might have been produced before the program fails.

You could try rewriting your Haskell program to check for end-of-file at the start of the loop:

```hs
import Control.Monad (when)
import System.IO (isEOF)

main = do
  guess_loop []

guess_loop xs = do
  eof <- isEOF
  when (not eof) $ do
    x <- readLn
    let new_list = x:xs
    putStr $ show $ doSomething new_list
    putStr "\n"
    guess_loop new_list
```

This probably looks very awkward, but as you become more experienced with Haskell, you'll discover that a more natural way of writing this program is something like:

```hs
import Data.List

main = do
  input <- getContents                  -- read all of stdin, lazily
  let values = map read (lines input)   -- read one value per line
  let output = map doSomething (tail (inits values))
     -- run the computation on every initial part of the list
  putStr $ unlines (map show output)    -- write outputs one per line
```

Comment: this works ! and I understand why, now. Many thanks.
"eof" and all stream notions were part of the things that I choose to overlook until it slap me in the face. But what slap you , might not always tells its name.

Comment: @fulverin As said in the bottom part of the answer, `eof` is actually rather seldom used explicitly. If you can just read the whole input in one go and write the output in one go (as in this case the JavaScript seems to require anyway), it becomes much easier. In fact this could be simplified even more with [`interact`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:interact).

Comment: @leftaroundabout 
in my case this the "other"/JS program that interact with "my" program feed one line only, wait for output and then, (only after) feed another line. 
The point of the exercise is to incrementally guess/describe a distribution; whose values are given one by one and each time I should provide a better guess.
Getting all lines in one time would kill the point of the exercise ( I tried indeed, but no easy win here )
but it looks like interact could make my code way fancier, Thanks